# The Ubuntu 14.04 iso

Tags: boot, iso

I downloadedUubuntu 14.04 .iso  which is 964MB file but when I create a bootable USB using unetbootin and yumi(I used both) it shows that total file size is 962 MB and after all everything goes normal.

But when I boot my desktop PC with the live USB it only shows Ubuntu startup logo with purple background and then nothing happen. And also when I burn the same .iso on a DVD the problem repeats.

Comment: Maybe check hamhut1066's answer for another question? [using dd to create bootable usb](http://askubuntu.com/a/449307/270879). It's basically just `sudo dd if=14.04.iso of=/dev/sdx`

Comment: More info is needed.  Add the output of `sudo lshw -C display` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.iso` file is corrupted. Download it again. The best way is to use torrent to be sure the right image has been downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Using dd to create boot USB DOES NOT WORK. I have to install tool here to create boot usb with 14.04 iso: http://www.linuxliveusb.com/ this for Windows and Mac only.